# MVC extra control password for confirmation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For some actions I want the user to retype his password. I do the check with an additional login, is that correct, and has the 2nd login any bad side effects?

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
public ActionResult SpecialAction()
{
   ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SpecialAction(string pwd)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwd) && WebSecurity.Login(User.Identity.Name, pwd))
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do the check with an additional login, is that correct, and has the 2nd login any bad side effects?

It is **perfectly legal and correct** way if you are giving user an access to a very sensitive area or information.

For example, if you are allowing a user to see his pass transactions on a E-commerce website, then you can ask for a password again. Secondly, you seem to ask password to the Administrator of the website, so in your case , you are giving him an access to very sensitive area of your website, so it is correct.